# Extract specific dictionaries from a list of nested dictionaries to a temp list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have been struggling to extract sub dictionaries where the value is "0" from a list of dictionaries and add them to temporary dictionaries.

I tried this:

```py
new_users = [{'user1':{'book1':'0', 'book2':'4', 'book3':'1'}},{'user2':{'book1':'5', 'book2':'1', 'book3':'0'}}]
    def approachA():
        for data in new_users:          # new_users is a list of nested dictionaries
            if data == '0':
                 print("found 0")
                 keys = data.keys()
                 for key in keys:
                     if key == '0':
                        key.pop() # tried to deleted delete the elements at first
```

It did not work for some reason, and I have been trying to do it for 2 hours so please do not ask questions not related to the problem.

This is a simple version of what I am trying to do:

```py
[{'user1':{'book1':'0', 'book2':'4', 'book3':'1'}},{'user2':{'book1':'5', 'book2':'1', 'book3':'0'}}] -> [{'user1':{'book1':'0'}}, {'user2':{'book3':'0'}}]
```

So basically the keys with value "0" get copied to a temp list of dictionaries.

Comment: My first thought is to use recursion. But you sure there will never be any collisions? At any level, the source data set could have more than one "book1", for example.

Comment: I'm having trouble relating your code snippet to the "simple version" example. I can help with how to do the transformation you have there, but based on the snippet I fear that it would not really solve your problem.

Comment: I tried recursion but I couldn't figure how to copy or delete the elements I want I can only access the values which don't make deleting the elements possible, as for collision I already filtered the Data so there will be no duplicates for sure. I will include the code again with all the referenced variables needed for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment I'm not sure this will solve your problem, but based on the sample transformation you gave, here's one way to achieve it:

```
LIST_IN = [{"name": {"book1": "0", "book2": "1", "book3": "0"}}]

def proccess(list_in):
    result = []

    for this_dict in list_in:
        for key in this_dict["name"]:
            if this_dict["name"][key] == "0":
                result.append({key: this_dict["name"][key]})

    return result

print(proccess(LIST_IN))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish the "sample" snippet. Please give some additional details if this is not what you were trying.

```
def solve_nested(nested_dict: list) -> list:
    result = list()
    for dictionary in nested_dict:
        for k, v in dictionary.items():
            for _k, _v in v.items():
                if _v == '0':
                    result.append({_k: _v})
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(solve_nested([{"name": {"book1": "0", "book2": "1", "book3": "0"}}]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in recursion, the below example ought to get you going:

```
# d_xy => x = nest level
#         y = dictionary item in nest level x

d = {'d_00' : {'d_10' : {'d_20' : 0,
                         'd_21' : 43,
                         'd_22' : 12},
               'd_11' : 4,
               'd_12' : 0,
               'd_13' : 1},
     'd_01' : 0,
     'd_02' : {'d_14' : {'d_23' : 0,
                         'd_24' : 1,
                         'd_25' : 0},
               'd_15' : 4,
               'd_16' : {'d_26' : 0,
                         'd_27' : {'d_30' : 3,
                                   'd_31' : 0,
                                   'd_32' : {'d_40' : 0},
                                   'd_33' : 0},
                         'd_28' : 1},
               'd_17' : 0}}

important_items = []

def get_0_key_values(dic):

    for key in dic:
        if type(dic[key]) == dict:
            get_0_key_values(dic[key])
        else:
            if dic[key] == 0:
                important_items.append({key : dic[key]})

get_0_key_values(d)

print(important_items)
```